# Is it possible to save PDF to TIFF multipaged with progress with ByteScout PDF Renderer SDK

Tags: c#, pdf

ByteScout PDF Renderer SDK – C# – PDF to TIFF multipaged example in blow, you can convert pdf to multipaged tiff. But I wonder, how can I convert to pages with progress.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Bytescout.PDFRenderer;

namespace PDF2TIFF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Create Bytescout.PDFRenderer.RasterRenderer object instance and register it.
            RasterRenderer renderer = new RasterRenderer();
            renderer.RegistrationName = "demo";
            renderer.RegistrationKey = "demo";

            // Load PDF document.
            renderer.LoadDocumentFromFile("multipage.pdf");

            int startPage = 0;
            int endPage = renderer.GetPageCount() - 1;

            // Save PDF document to black-and-white multi-page TIFF at 120 DPI
            RenderingOptions renderingOptions = new RenderingOptions();
            renderingOptions.TIFFCompression = TIFFCompression.CCITT4;
            renderer.SaveMultipageTiff("multipage.tiff", startPage, endPage, 120, renderingOptions);

            // Cleanup
            renderer.Dispose();

            // Open result document in default associated application (for demo purpose)
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("multipage.tiff");
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Bytescout.PDFRenderer;

namespace PDF2TIFF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Create Bytescout.PDFRenderer.RasterRenderer object instance and register it.
            RasterRenderer renderer = new RasterRenderer();
            renderer.RegistrationName = "demo";
            renderer.RegistrationKey = "demo";

            // Load PDF document.
            renderer.LoadDocumentFromFile("multipage.pdf");

            // ProgressChanged here...
            renderer.ProgressChanged += RasterRenderer_ProgressChanged;

            int startPage = 0;
            int endPage = renderer.GetPageCount() - 1;

            // Save PDF document to black-and-white multi-page TIFF at 120 DPI
            RenderingOptions renderingOptions = new RenderingOptions();
            renderingOptions.TIFFCompression = TIFFCompression.CCITT4;
            renderer.SaveMultipageTiff("multipage.tiff", startPage, endPage, 120, renderingOptions);

            // Cleanup
            renderer.Dispose();

            // Open result document in default associated application (for demo purpose)
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("multipage.tiff");
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        }

        private void RasterRenderer_ProgressChanged(object sender, OngoingOperation og, double p, ref bool cancel)
        {
            var per = 100 * decimal.Divide(Convert.ToDecimal(p), 100);
            label1.Update();
            label1.Text = $@"{per:F2}% completed.";
        }
    }
}
```